# Highcharts leave selected like on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to make custom selection, on select I want to leave the selection layer pointed in image: 
[image]

```
chart: {
            events: {
                selection: function (event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   event.xAxis[0].axis.chart.series[0].points.forEach(function (point) {
                             point.select(true, true);
                   })
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
```

Example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8nbapeu/), but I just selected the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a plot band which looks exactly the same as the selection fill.

```
selection: function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               var axis = this.xAxis[0];

               axis.removePlotBand('selection-plot-band');

               axis.addPlotBand({
                color: Highcharts.color('#335cad').setOpacity(0.25).get() //use Highcharts.Color in version 4,
                from: e.xAxis[0].min,
                to: e.xAxis[0].max,
                id: 'selection-plot-band',
                zIndex: 6
               });
            }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L8nbapeu/1/

Comment: I get  Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.color is not a function, how to fix it?

Comment: It should be Highcharts.Color('#335cad')

Comment: You are right, Highcharts.color works in version 5+, with version 4.x must be Highcharts.Color